# Taming wormholes

Tags: space, space-travel, universe, wormholes

An ancient civilization mapped wormholes when the universe was quite young and smaller. This allowed them to reach other galaxies (wormholes from our galaxy to others). They mapped it all.

Humans found their maps in recent times, and now humanity is able to reach anywere in the universe thanks to those maps.

The question:

If there are wormholes in the early universe (let's suppose leading from the Milky Way to Andromeda), and the universe expands to a larger sphere, would those wormholes expand together with the universe, keeping  the same relative positions to other celestial bodies, effectively becoming a space-highway system when properly mapped?

Comment: I would worry more about what happens to those celestial bodies.....if a planet was habitable a billion years ago what are the chances it is still habitable or even there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the ends of a wormhole basically behave like a normal celestial body (assuming there's no additional physics not yet known to us that affects their movement). They would move with the expanding universe, and they might even orbit a star. However I have no idea what the apparent mass of a wormhole would be; it might as well be that the star orbits the wormhole, or even that (since wormholes need to be filled with negative energy density to be stable) they would be of negative mass and thus repel the matter around.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that the ends of a wormhole behave like a normal celestial body? Especially since in the next section you say they would have negative mass - in which case they would fly away from solar systems and end up as deep in intergalactic space as they could get...

Comment: The source will have to wait until I'm back home (I'm abroad and don't have the resources here). And about the negative mass: You misunderstood. First, I'm not saying that it *would have* negative mass, but only that I *cannot exclude* that a stabilized wormhole would end up having negative mass. And second, you're wrong in that a body of negative mass would be expelled from the galaxy; it's still attracted and follows the same path as a positive mass particle, even in Newtonian physics (do the math; but remember that the mass also enters in Newton's equation); in General Relativity, the …

Comment: … equivalence principle guarantees it (indeed, in GR, the mass of an object does not even enter into its equation of motion; objects just follow geodesics of the space time). Note that this doesn't change the fact that objects of positive mass would be repelled by the negative-mass body.

Answer (score 3):

The more important thing for such travel is having the technology to travel to these worm holes, rather than just locate them on a map.

Since the ancient civilization *was able to reach* these wormholes, we must assume one of the two

**1. They had efficient space travel technology**

If even their technology was good, ours would have become incredibly better and we would know and be able to reach many more wormholes than them. Their work would only have historical importance. This is the most likely case if i am to take your words literally (*and now humanity is able to reach anywhere in the universe thanks to those maps.*)

If they were a civilization apart from us, then we would not be able to access, or even predict where they would be now. Wormholes and expansion of the universe are still only theories, so we cannot exactly calculate their positions as of today. Even if we knew the rate of expansion of the universe down to a single kilometer, there a number of other factors, such as gravity of near by bodies, mass sucked by wormhole ever since, velocity at which one is pulled in, etc. which we have no idea whatsoever of.

**2. The wormhole entrances were located on the earth**

There is a minute chance they are still here (if 'expansion of the universe' is a false theory) but I wouldn't think so. If they are, good for us because

(a) we can use the wormholes

(b) we have good proof for proving Big Bang false, and researching into new theories.

Comment: Expansion of the universe isn't a theory; it's an observation. And how could this prove the Big Bang theory false?

Comment: @HDE226868 If the Big Bang really happened, space would continue to expand until there is a good reason for it to just stop expanding one fine day. I'm not sure it can prove Big Bang false, maybe you can ask on the Physics SE.